# Xcodeでナビゲーターエリアのアイコンが黒く曇っているのは何を意味していますか？

Tags: swift, xcode

非常に初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、ご回答宜しくお願い致します。
Swift言語にてXcodeアプリ開発を行っているのですが、ふとナビゲーターエリアを見てみると、アイコンが黒く曇っていました。
Main.Storyboardと各ViewControllerはクラスの設定も済んでおり、接続済みという状況です。

この状態でビルドしても何も問題はなく、起動されているのですが何か意味があるのでしょうか？(設定し忘れている事柄がある、など)

お詳しい方がいましたら、どうかご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 「ふとナビゲーターエリアを見てみると、アイコンが黒く曇っていました」とありますが、画像のキャプチャを貼り付けると回答者の助けになると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

少し曇ってるという状態でしたら、それは未保存（編集したが保存してない）状態だと思います。
通常の設定ではビルド実行したりXCodeを閉じる際に自動保存され、曇ってる状態はクリアされます。
クリアされないとすると、何らかのXCode,macOS,maxマシンの不具合かもしれませんし、他の原因があるかもしれませんね。